# How to increase number of history items shown in powershell command completion (predictionview)?

Tags: powershell

The powershell command completion drop down selector shows at most 10 items.  I was looking in the PS settings, but did not find any setting for the max number of items shown.

```
# Get-PSReadLineOption
EditMode                               : Windows
AddToHistoryHandler                    : System.Func`2[System.String,System.Object]
HistoryNoDuplicates                    : True
HistorySavePath                        : C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt
HistorySaveStyle                       : SaveIncrementally
HistorySearchCaseSensitive             : False
HistorySearchCursorMovesToEnd          : False
MaximumHistoryCount                    : 4096
ContinuationPrompt                     : >>
ExtraPromptLineCount                   : 0
PromptText                             :
BellStyle                              : Audible
DingDuration                           : 50
DingTone                               : 1221
CommandsToValidateScriptBlockArguments : {ForEach-Object, %, Invoke-Command, icm…}
CommandValidationHandler               :
CompletionQueryItems                   : 100
MaximumKillRingCount                   : 10
ShowToolTips                           : True
ViModeIndicator                        : None
WordDelimiters                         : ;:,.[]{}()/\|!?^&*-=+'"–—―
AnsiEscapeTimeout                      : 100
PredictionSource                       : History
PredictionViewStyle                    : ListView
TerminateOrphanedConsoleApps           : False
CommandColor                           : "`e[93m"
...
```

[image]

**How can I increase the list to show 20 items?**

Comment: Looks like 10 is a hardcoded limit in the history plugin: https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/ff4bbd5ee0e2dea7d72e0adb43d64a3f07c0e7e1/PSReadLine/Prediction.Views.cs#L213

Comment: Woa! Yep, looks like it's defined by [ListViewMaxHeight](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/ff4bbd5ee0e2dea7d72e0adb43d64a3f07c0e7e1/PSReadLine/Prediction.Views.cs#L213) and setting also using `HistoryMaxCount` as list items? What a shame.